# Selecting custom element with document selector

Tags: javascript, typescript, stenciljs

I am writing an application in Stenciljs and my custom element is as follows:

```
<custom-alert alertType="warning" alertId="warningMessage" hide>Be warned</custom-alert>
```

Now, the issue is with selecting this element via `document.querySelector()` or any other possibility to remove or add the `hide` attribute. This can be done for standard HTML elements easily:

```
document.querySelector('input').removeAttribute('hide');
```

How can I do this for my custom element?

Comment: did you try `document.querySelector('custom-alert').removeAttribute('hide');` ?

Comment: You can also add an id, or use any other way of selecting it. The fact that the tag is custom doesn't matter. You usually wouldn't use `document.querySelector('input')` anyway, given that it arbitrarily selects whatever the first <input> on the page is

Comment: Is `hide` a `@Prop` of the `custom-alert` component or just an attribute (e.g. for styling)?

Comment: Not prop, but a standard HTML attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired result by adding an id attribute

```
<custom-alert id="myCustomAlert" alertType="warning" alertId="warningMessage" >Be warned</custom-alert>
```

Then this component can be hidden and shown as follows:

```
document.getElementById('myCustomAlert').setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
```

And shown as follows:

```
document.getElementById('myCustomAlert').removeAttribute('hidden');
```